# LOad different instances of the same NSViewController on NSTabView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, viewcontroller, nstabview

I have a NSTabView, where I alloc and load the same NSViewController on its tabs:

```
IRCView *viewirc = [[IRCView alloc] initWithNibName:@"IRCView" bundle:nil];
for (id view in [tabsView tabViewItems]) {
     [view setView:[viewirc view]];
}
```

How could I load different 'instances' of `IRCView` view controller on each of the `NSTabView` tabs? So each tab can have a different connection to the IRC server (in this example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(NSTabViewItem * tabViewItem in [tabsView tabViewItems])
{
    // instantiate a brand new IRCView for each tab view item...
    IRCView *viewirc = [[IRCView alloc] initWithNibName:@"IRCView" bundle:nil];

    // ... and do whatever customization you want to do for each IRCView here

    [tabViewItem setView: viewirc];
    [viewirc release]; // tabViewItem already retains
}
```